# How to use Javascript to show a "loading" sign until the series of redirect finishes

Tags: javascript, redirect

I am trying to set up a affiliate site.

the links which i put up on the website will go through a series of redirects before reaching the final page.

ie my site -> site A -> site B -> final site 
(i can see this from my address bar)

how to i make it show the loading sign until the final site is ready to be displayed and that the address for site A and site B do not appear on the address bar?

i have the code to get the "loading" sign running... but i do not know how to do the second part.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say redirects? Do you mean with content to view?

Comment: I don't think this is possible (if the redirects are at page-level). Consider that at each 'redirect' actually results in a *new page/URI* context for the browser. Is there any *existing* site that you wish to emulate?

Comment: to re-clarify... i would like to have the loading image up until the redirects reaches my final page where i then display it.
http://www.shopstyle.com/browse/bridal-shoes?feat=221114517
this website seems to do it.. when you click the link, a new window appears and from the status bar, i see it jumping through a few sites before loading the final one...
i hope i am not too confusing or i assumed something wrongly. pretty much a newbie here..